# Xpath error message "exceptions.ValueError: Invalid XPath:"

Tags: xpath, scrapy

I try to use xpath to get the @content attribute of the following html code:

```
<meta content="52222" name="DCSext.job_id">
```

I use this xpath code as a portion of scrapy spider:

```
    def parse(self, response):
    hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
    sites = hxs.select('//*')    

    for site in sites:
        il = DataItemLoader(response=response, selector=site)
        il.add_xpath('listing_id', 'meta[@name="DCSext.job_id"]@content')
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        il.add_xpath('loc_pj', substring-after('h1[@class="title heading"]/text()',':'))
        il.add_xpath('title', 'head/title/text()')
        il.add_xpath('post_date', 'div[@id="extr"]/div/dl/dd[3]/text()')
        il.add_xpath('web_url', 'head/link[@rel="canon"]@href')
        yield il.load_item()
```

I got the error message of of the underlined code:

```
 exceptions.ValueError: Invalid XPath:  meta[@name="DCSext.job_id"]@content
```

How to fix this?  Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct code should be:

```
meta[@name="DCSext.job_id"]/@content
                           ^
```